# How to process a dictionary of strings in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of values that follow this string pattern `informationGain_$index$` and `threshold_$index$`. My goal is to retrieve the maximum informationGain_$index$ and `threshold_$index$`.

An example dictionary looks like so:

```
{'informationGain_0': 0.9949486404805016, 'threshold_0': 5.0, 'informationGain_1': 0.9757921620455572, 'threshold_1': 12.5, 'informationGain_2': 0.7272727272727273, 'threshold_2': 11.5, 'informationGain_3': 0.5509775004326937, 'threshold_3': 8.6, 'informationGain_4': 0.9838614413637048, 'threshold_4': 7.0, 'informationGain_5': 0.9512050593046015, 'threshold_5': 6.0, 'informationGain_6': 0.8013772106338303, 'threshold_6': 5.9, 'informationGain_7': 0.9182958340544896, 'threshold_7': 1.5, 'informationGain_8': 0.0, 'threshold_8': 9.0, 'informationGain_9': 0.6887218755408672, 'threshold_9': 7.8, 'informationGain_10': 0.9182958340544896, 'threshold_10': 2.1, 'informationGain_11': 0.0, 'threshold_11': 13.5}
```

I written code to generate the dataset.

```
def entropy_discretization(s):

    I = {}
    i = 0
    while(uniqueValue(s)):
        # Step 1: pick a threshold
        threshold = s['A'].iloc[0]

        # Step 2: Partititon the data set into two parttitions
        s1 = s[s['A'] < threshold]
        print("s1 after spitting")
        print(s1)
        print("******************")
        s2 = s[s['A'] >= threshold]
        print("s2 after spitting")
        print(s2)
        print("******************")
            
        # Step 3: calculate the information gain.
        informationGain = information_gain(s1,s2,s)
        I.update({f'informationGain_{i}':informationGain,f'threshold_{i}': threshold})
        print(f'added informationGain_{i}: {informationGain}, threshold_{i}: {threshold}')
        s = s[s['A'] != threshold]
        i += 1

    print(I)
```

Given the example dataset, the maximum information gain is associated with `threshold_0` and `informationGain_0`. I would like to find a general way of identifying these key values pairs from the dataset. Is there a way to search the dictionary such that I can return `informationGain_*,threshold_*` such that `informationGain_* == max`?

Comment: is there any particular reason you are structuring your data like this instead of using say a `set` of `namedtuple`s? Or just 2 parallel dicts where the key is just the index, or just a list of `namedtuple`s if all indices will exist, or even a list of dicts that only have the keys `informationGain` and `threshold` if you don't like named tuples. All of those representations makes this task a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using a custom key with `max`. It works even if the dictionary is not sorted. This is assuming the input dictionary is named `d`.

```
M = max((k for k in d if k.startswith('i')),
        key=lambda x: d[x])
T = f'threshold_{M.rsplit("_")[-1]}'
out = {M: d[M], T: d[T]}
```

Output:

```
{'informationGain_0': 0.9949486404805016, 'threshold_0': 5.0}
```

*NB. I used a simple test on the dictionary keys to check those that start with `i` in order to identify the `informationGain_X` keys. If you have a more complex real life dictionary, you might want to update this to use a full match or any other way to make identification of the key non ambiguous.*

Comment: +1 this is a great answer. I have one small gripe which is that `k.startswith('i')` is a relatively weak conditional. I think regex would be a more appropriate choice: `r"informationGain_(\d*)"`.

Comment: @ddejohn I hesitated to put a longer string and decided on the simplest solution given OP's data. Also a simpler conditional means a faster code. But I'll add a comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found a way of doing this. It just took a few tries

```
    n = int(((len(I)/2)-1))
    print("Calculating maximum threshold")
    print("*****************************")
    maxInformationGain = 0
    maxThreshold       = 0 
    for i in range(0, n):
        if(I[f'informationGain_{i}'] > maxInformationGain):
            maxInformationGain = I[f'informationGain_{i}']
            maxThreshold       = I[f'threshold_{i}']

    print(f'maxThreshold: {maxThreshold}, maxInformationGain: {maxInformationGain}')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is as follows:

assuming your dictionary name is `d`

```
informationGain_max = max(list(d.values())[::2])
threshold_max = max(list(d.values())[1::2])
```

this only works under the assumption that since python 3.6 standard dict maintains the order of insertions.

Comment: I'd significantly prefer a solution that uses `filter` or `sort` or list comprehension with a condition, making a list and slicing seems like such a bad idea with something that is logically an unordered set

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I agree. i think that even using ordered items like `informationGain_i` and `threshold_i` in a dict is already a bad idea because elements on a dict are not supposed to be ordered.

Answer (score -1):

Lets make a list, and each member of that list should be a tuple or list that contains two elements: first the information gain, and then the threshold. We can sort this list with either the .sort() method of the list or by using the sorted() function. The last tuple of the sorted list will contain the values you seek. If you are also interested in the index of these values then add their index as a third element of the tuples.